Can’t connect docker daemon server
I'm using Rancher Desktop as docker daemon with its container engine setting dockerd(moby).
When I run docker info, got:
Client:
 Version:    26.1.0-rd
 Context:    rancher-desktop
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.14.1
    Path:     /Users/user1/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.27.1
    Path:     /Users/user1/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///Users/user1/.rd/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info

But I can see the docker.sock file:
ls -la /Users/user1/.rd/docker.sock
srw-------@ 1 user1  staff  0  6 26 11:44 /Users/user1/.rd/docker.sock

Why the server can't connect?

Check this in Preferences window, then apply.

In the popup page, check Always run without administrative access.
